# mixin is not found in different scss file

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am learning Angular and scss as well. So in my test Angular v.5 Project currently facing problems with @mixin. Note that default.styleExt also set to 'scss'. @mixin works fine if I use @mixin and @include in the same *.scss file. But When I try to use @include of that @mixin in a different *.scss file. It shows errors.

For example, in my

> styles.scss

has this mixin,

```
@mixin breakpoint($screen){
    @if $screen == window_xLarge { 
        @media (min-width: 1440px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $screen == window_large { 
        @media (min-width: 1280px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $screen == window_medium { 
        @media (min-width: 840px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $screen == window_small { 
        @media (min-width: 600px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $screen == window_xSmall { 
        @media (min-width: 480px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to use this @mixin in one of my other components' '*.scss', for example,
in

> comp01.scss

try to add this code

```
app-comp02{
    width: 100%;
    @include breakpoint(window_small){
        width: 50%
    }
    @include breakpoint(window_medium){
        width: 50%;
    }
    @include breakpoint(window_large){
        width: 33%;
    }
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

It shows error like this

```
Module build failed:
    @include breakpoint(window_small){
            ^
      No mixin named breakpoint
```

Does anyone know, why this is happening? I definitely do not want to put all codes in the same scss file. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your mixins in a _helpers.scss file and then include that file in both your different scss like this

```
@import "/helpers";  // Path of scss
```

Or you can simply import "styles.scss" in the "comp01.scss" using the same syntax as mentioned above

Comment: I guess, this is the only solution for now. Although I did not want to import in the every file I use that @mixin.

Comment: It is how it works in angular. Even I faced this issue. This was the only thing that worked for me. I am telling by experience. If you find something else for this let me know in this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your typing you have an error because you should write the media query like that and this is a [good site:sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) to test your **sass/scss** you can paste your code and you will see the errors

```
@mixin breakpoint($screen){
    @if $screen == window_xLarge { 
        @media screen and (min-width: 1440px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $screen == window_large { 
        @media screen and (min-width: 1280px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $screen == window_medium { 
        @media screen and (min-width: 840px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $screen == window_small { 
        @media screen and (min-width: 600px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else if $screen == window_xSmall { 
        @media screen and (min-width: 480px){ 
            @content;
        }
    }
}

app-comp02{
    width: 100%;
    @include breakpoint(window_small){
        width: 50%
    }
    @include breakpoint(window_medium){
        width: 50%;
    }
    @include breakpoint(window_large){
        width: 33%;
    }
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

and you wrote it like that

```
   @media (min-width: 1280px){ 
            @content;
        }
```

Comment: Well, I have mentioned that it works if they are in the same *.scss file. So I guess @media (min-width: ****px) also ok. I found this way writing 
https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-responsive-breakpoints-sass/ 
and 
https://responsivedesign.is/develop/getting-started-with-sass-and-breakpoint-mixin/